# How do you make a report template for a single Enterprise Architect diagram?

Tags: templates, diagram, enterprise-architect

I have a package with about 25 diagrams in it. I have used EA templates to make a package report that gives the name and notes for each diagram. However I want make a more specific report that can generates the report for just one diagram containing the description from each element in the diagram. Is this possible? It does not seem like diagrams have anywhere I can generate reports from.

UPDATE: I am currently trying to figure out how to do this with Document Options>Except where Query excludes Package:>Custom SQL but cannot get it. Here is my SQL statement:

```
SELECT t_diagram.ea_guid & t_diagram.Name AS [DesiredService-Hyperlink]
FROM t_diagram
WHERE t_diagram.Name = 'Diagram_Name'
```

I tried putting this in the Report's Custom SQL, that didn't work. Then I tried putting it in a fragment's Custom SQL with the following in the template itself

```
custom >
{DesiredService-Hyperlink}
< custom
```

This also did not work. I have been trying to go off of various documentation and YouTube Videos. If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enterprise Architect document generation is based more on the model structure then on the diagrams.

The easiest approach would be to put each diagram in a different package or nested under a specific element, even if only temporary to generate the document.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am going to leave it open for another day or two, but if no one has a better answer I will mark as closed. My company will not restructure the files so this isn't a 'solution' for me. Although I understand it may be the best/only solution.